# Android how to answer phone, etc with headset button?

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure how to get started here so I'll ask a fairly general question.

Let's say I have a plug-in headset with a button. Now if I have an incoming phone call, can I programmatically make it so that when the user clicks the button on the headset, it answers (or rejects) the call? I can already register the headset clicks so that's not an issue. Also eventually I need to do a multitude of functions such as play/pause music with the button (if the music player is open).

Mostly I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The built-in Phone and Music app already support media buttons(headset button) and have the similar behavior.
2. If you want your app to be the sole receiver of media button events: 
   [AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver%28android.content.ComponentName%29)